# Does "have a sore head" have the same meaning as "have a headache"?

Tags: meaning

The post title is my very question. Does *have a sore head* have any meaning other than *have a headache*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mari-Lou A noted, *have a sore head* may refer to having an injured head, or to experiencing the effects of too much alcohol (having a hangover).  Eg:  “Don't blink so loudly at me like that, I have a sore head”.

The term associated with anger is *[sorehead](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sorehead)*, not *sore head*.  It means  “A person who has a tendency to be angry or to feel offended” and might be used in phrases like *sorehead loser* or sentences like  “He's a sorehead if you cross him”.

Answer (score 2):

If someone banged me on the head with a blunt instrument, I would have a ***very sore head***. 
I would also have a large red bump on my head to prove it.

If I had drunk a little too much wine for dinner, I might wake up the next day with a ***throbbing head***.

A *throbbing head* describes one type of headache. I wouldn't normally say  *sore head* myself, but if someone else used that expression and I saw no visible wounds or bruises on their head I would know what they mean.

Comment: Thank you. Does it have any other meanings like "getting angry" or something?

Comment: I think in American English "**to be sore** at someone" can mean to be angry. I would need to check in a dictionary to be absolutely certain. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sore Look at definition 6.

Comment: Mari-LouA: Great answer, I agree :) +1! I too would understand *sore head*, but agree that it isn't idiomatic to say. (And *throbbing* is a great related word!) To my ear, *to be sore at someone* sounds British, but it might be a regionalism (I'm from the US, but all AmE speakers are of course not the same :)). (cc @dennylv)

Comment: @Mari-LouA To this Brit, "to be sore at someone" is definitely American.